# How to find contours of only brown areas on an image?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, contour

I have been trying to find contours of brown areas on my frame.

[image: frame]

I tried to find these contours in a `for` loop.

```
    for c in cntrs:
        area = cv2.contourArea(c)
        if area > 1200:   # i obtanied threshold with trial end error
            x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(c) #find coordinates of brown area
            roi2 = results[y:y + h, x:x + w] #copy these parts to the another image
```

but i can see only one contour as result

[image: result]

i couldn't understand why i see only one contour. because when i print number of thresholded contours i see `2`

here is what i tried

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0) ##masaustunde 1, laptopta 0


def nothing(x):
    pass

roi = cv2.imread('savedImage.jpg')
cv2.imshow('input', roi)
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(roi, cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV)

lower_green = np.array([0, 0, 0])
upper_green = np.array([40, 255, 255])

mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_green, upper_green)
mask_inv = cv2.bitwise_not(mask)

fg = cv2.bitwise_and(roi, roi, mask=mask_inv)

gray = cv2.cvtColor(fg, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(fg, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 32, 255, 0)[1]
cntrs = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cntrs = cntrs[0] if len(cntrs) == 2 else cntrs[1]
area_thresh = 0
syc = 0
results = fg.copy()
for c in cntrs:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area > 1200: #esige dikkat
        syc = syc + 1
        x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        roi2 = results[y:y + h, x:x + w]
cv2.imshow('roi2', roi2)

cv2.waitKey(0)


capture.release()  # release the camera from video capture
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: You have included black (0,0,0) as your lower range. So that includes your background.

Comment: how it can find first contour, then?

Comment: View your fg image and make sure your upper and lower ranges find your two regions and they are not connected. Also that the whole image is not one big region, since your lower range includes (0,0,0). Also try a lower area threshold than 1200. Perhaps that is too high. (Always best to view the result of each step to see that they look as expected).

Comment: i didn't post here to reduce size of code but i added `imshow` to each step and i can see they are not connected. also as i said, i can see that number of `syc` is 2 (number of regions which have area bigger than 1200) . i use (0,0,0) but also i am using inverse of that mask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are writing over the results (roi2) in your loop without waiting to view each one. You have to put the waitKey() into the loop.

Also as I said before, your area threshold was too high.

I also chose better lower and upper thresholds. (I save the hsv file and then measured its values in GUI tool)

This works for me in Python/OpenCV. Press the return key after each roi2 is displayed to go on to the next one.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

roi = cv2.imread('green_areas.jpg')
#cv2.imshow('input', roi)

hsv = cv2.cvtColor(roi, cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV)
#cv2.imshow('hsv', hsv)

lower_green = np.array([30, 30, 30])
upper_green = np.array([60, 140, 100])

mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_green, upper_green)
#cv2.imshow('mask', mask)

mask_inv = cv2.bitwise_not(mask)

fg = cv2.bitwise_and(roi, roi, mask=mask_inv)
#cv2.imshow('fg', fg)

gray = cv2.cvtColor(fg, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 32, 255, 0)[1]
#cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)

cntrs = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cntrs = cntrs[0] if len(cntrs) == 2 else cntrs[1]
area_thresh = 0
syc = 0
results = fg.copy()
for c in cntrs:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area > 500: #esige dikkat
        syc = syc + 1
        x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        roi2 = results[y:y + h, x:x + w]
        cv2.imshow('roi2', roi2)
        cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```